# how to change "CSRF token mismatch" message?

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf-token

I'm using larvel 8 and want to change message of "CSRF token mismatch" when using ajax post. I created a closure and passed it to the renderable method on the App\Exceptions\Handler class, but the previews message appears.
This is my code:

```php
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (TokenMismatchException $e, $request) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => 'A new message...'], 419)
                : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
        });    
    }
```

Comment: here your using `$request->expectsJson()` means in ajax you need to pass header `Accept: application/json`

Answer (score 3):

### To modify error message on TokenMismatchException both for web-pages and ajax-requests

It would be better to overload `prepareException()` method in application exception handler:

```php
    protected function prepareException(Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
            $e = new HttpException(419, __('exception.csrf_token_mismatch'), $e);
        }

        return parent::prepareException($e);
    }
```

So you can create translation file and modify message by language files. For example create `resources/lang/en/exception.php` with content below:

```php
<?php

return [
    'csrf_token_mismatch' => 'CSRF token mismatch. Please, refresh page (CTRL+R) and try again.',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to everyone who contributed, I found the solution.

Due to laravel change the TokenMismatchException to HttpException in the function prepareException in the Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler class(parent of Handler class), we cannot render the TokenMismatchException.

```php
protected function prepareException(Throwable $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            $e = new AccessDeniedHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
            $e = new HttpException(419, $e->getMessage(), $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof SuspiciousOperationException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException('Bad hostname provided.', $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof RecordsNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException('Not found.', $e);
        }

        return $e;
    }
```

I modify my renderable method as below and now I can catch the TokenMismatchException:

```php
$this->renderable(function (HttpException $e, $request) {
    if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' =>'Your new message ...', 419)
            : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to change the error message or the page that is shown when CSRF token mismatch happen

Run this command: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors`

It will publish your default (vendor) exceptions page to `resources/views/errors/`

From there, edit `resources/views/errors/419.blade.php` with html that you would like to show when CSRF verification error happen.

References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

```
419 Page Expired (Laravel Framework)
    Used by the Laravel Framework when a CSRF Token is missing or expired.
```

### If you want to allow ajax requests to bypass CSRF token verification

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Edit your VerifyCsrfToken middleware (location: `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`), add:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I used an ajax post request. Before the session expired, everything worked fine, but this request gets the message "CSRF token mismatch" once it expired. I want to translate this message to another language. Due to ajax request, changing the 419 error blade file is not beneficial.

Comment: @HamidRezaValizadeh see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization for translation